# ringcaptcha Api For Sms Send i have use but this not Working

Tags: api, sms

how to Use ringcaptcha Api For Sms Send

POST /${app_key}/normalize HTTP/1.1

Host: https://api.ringcaptcha.com

Content-Type: application/x-www-url-encoded; charset=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

that's the endpoint for normalization, you need to call the /code/sms endpoint for sending verification SMS. post here the code you are using to see if there are any issues.